# delete a listview that retrieves from database

Tags: android, database, listview, android-studio

I have a list view of user answers (exam result),this listView get answers of exam from database and I want to delete this list view too, in the activity I made a button(not in list view)witch deletes the list view but when I click the button gives me this error I know this error happened because I didn't set exam year and question number but I don't know how to do it in my button onClick in list view:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String
    com.example.eric.myapp6.model.User_answer.getKonkoor_num()' on a null object reference 
    at com.example.eric.myapp6.database.DataBase.deleteUser(DataBase.java:140)
        at com.example.eric.myapp6.exam_resault.pasokh_azmoon$1.onClick(pasokh_azmoon.java:50)
```

User answer is a class that I used for get set methods.

Here is my database class:

```
private static final String TABLE_FAVOURITE_QUESTIONS = "favourite_questions";
private static final String TABLE_USER_EXAM = "User_exam";
private static final String TABLE_EXAM_FINAL_PERCENT = "Exam_final_percent";

private static final String Tozih = "tozih";
private static final String Saal = "saal";
private static final String Title = "title";

//private static final String EXAM_NUM = "exam_num";
private static final String KONKOOR_NUM = "konkoor_num";
private static final String QUESTION_NUM = "question_num";
private static final String USEER_ANSWER = "user_answer";

private static final String TAG = "DataBase";


public DataBase(Context context)
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String CREATE_FAVOURITE_GHAVAED_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_FAVOURITE_GHAVAED + "("
            + Saal + " TEXT,"
            + Title + " TEXT" + ")";
    String CREATE_FAVOURITE_QUESTIONS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_FAVOURITE_QUESTIONS + "("
            + KONKOOR_NUM + " TEXT,"
            + QUESTION_NUM + " TEXT" + ")";
    String CREATE_USER_EXAM_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER_EXAM + "("
            + KONKOOR_NUM + " TEXT,"
            + QUESTION_NUM + " TEXT,"
            + USEER_ANSWER + " TEXT" + ")";
    String CREATE_EXAM_FINAL_PERCENT = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_EXAM_FINAL_PERCENT + "("
            + KONKOOR_NUM + " TEX" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_FAVOURITE_GHAVAED_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_FAVOURITE_QUESTIONS_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_EXAM_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_EXAM_FINAL_PERCENT);

}


@Override

//user answer is a set get class of exam year and question numbers
public void deleteUser(User_answer user_answer) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] args = new String []{ user_answer.getKonkoor_num(), user_answer.getQuestion_num()};
    db.delete(TABLE_USER_EXAM, " konkoor_num =? AND question_num=?", args);
    Log.i("getUserExam", "deleting done!");
    db.close();
}
```

and here is my exam result list view class all answers with year and question numbers are in this list:

```
public class pasokh_azmoon extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<User_answer> list;
    Button delete_exam;
    User_answer us;
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pasokh_azmoon);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        setTitle("پاسخ آزمون");
        final DataBase db = new DataBase(this);

        list = db.getAnswer();
        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.pasokh_azmon_listview);
        final pasokh_azmoon_adapter adapter = new pasokh_azmoon_adapter(getApplicationContext(), list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
//BUTTON I USED OUTSIDE THE LIST VIEW TO DELETE LIST
        delete_exam = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete_exam);
        delete_exam.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
//this is where I get the error
                us.setKonkoor_num();
                us.setQuestion_num();
                db.deleteUser(us);
            }
        });
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                db.deleteUser_Exam(list.get(position).getKonkoor_num(), list.get(position).getQuestion_num());
            }
        });
    }
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            finish();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: where you implement deleteUser methid?

Comment: in databse and listview delete_exam onclick @mohammadreza khalifeh